# mantine/core v5.9.5 import components the prompt can not be used as a JSX component

Tags: reactjs, mantine

When I used the Mantine/core component, the prompt didn't work as a JSX component, but the component worked and the project worked

```
system: 2022 MacBookPro MacOs version:13.4 Apple M2 chip
node: v 16.14.0
npm: v 8.3.1
yarn: v 1.22.17
mantine/core: v 5.9.5
```

```
import React from 'react'
import { Box } from '@mantine/core'
import Deal from './Deal'
import History from './History'

const H5Gird = () => {
  return <Box>test</Box>
}

export default H5Gird
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnf1J.png)

The above is my problem description, I hope that some people encounter similar problems can help me to solve it

Comment: Box component file name end with .jsx?